# how to override mage_checkout_model_cart?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart, overrides, model

i want override mage/checkout/model/cart.php

to company/module/model/cart.php

i want to override

```
public function save()
{

}
```

how to override core checkout model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) you should have create company_module.xml at the app/etc/modules with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Company_Module>
              <active>true</active> 
              <codePool>local</codePool> 
            </Company_Module>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Step 2) In your modules config.xml at etc update with the following code.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart>Company_Module_Model_Cart</cart> 
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </models>
</global>
```

Step 3) now in your cart.php file at model/cart.php

```
<?php
    class Company_Module_Model_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart{

        public function save()
        {
            // add ur code here
        }
    }
```